# Nested-Components not working with Routing in Angular

Tags: angular, routes, components

I'm trying to learn angular with on my own project, I Started with handling Route path:`/` that's render `HomepageComponent` in `(app.routing.module.ts)`

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';
import { BestProductComponent } from './best-product/best-product.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomepageComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ BestProductComponent ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

`HomepageComponent(homepage.component.html)` want to render `BestProductComponent`

```html
<app-best-product></app-best-product>
```

But here, what I got:

> src/app/homepage/homepage.component.html (2:1)
> 'app-best-product' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'app-best-product' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'app-best-product' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

I'm Looking for solution for this problem, you can find the project in here
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-buj3sg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check weather you registered this component BestProductComponent in the app.module.ts like

```
    declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BestProductComponent
  ]
```

Also in the BestProductComponent .ts file check

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-best-product',
  ----------------------------
  ----------------------------
})
```

Comment: After add `BestProductComponent` in `app.module.ts`, That's what I got: `The Component 'BestProductComponent' is declared by more than one NgModule.`

Comment: Then you have to remove it from app.routing.mmodule and it should work with this answer :)

Comment: I will remove `BestProductComponent` from `app.routing.module.ts` and see.